# Why do these xsl:when tests always get evaluated as false?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file which is at http://pastie.org/9604783

I am using the following xsl with Saxon-HE and while it doesn't produce errors (so it should be correct syntax) none of the xsl:when statements seem to be evaluating as true because all the output tags are being wrapped in `<bodytext></bodytext>` according the `xsl:otherwise` statement.

The intended effect of these `xsl:when` statements is some variation of the following

IF `a:t` element has
a `<p.sld>` ancestor 
AND has an `<r>` ancestor which has an immediately-preceding sibling element which has an attribute:value pair of `lvl='1'` 
THEN output the contents of that `a:t` wrapped in `<bulleted></bulleted>`
OTHERWISE output the contents of that `a:t` wrapped in `<bodytext></bodytext>`

the variations on what tag the output should be wrapped in depend on if the ancestor is `<p.sld>` or `<p.notes>` and whether the `lvl` property has a value of 1, 2, or 3

Here's my XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:t"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//a:t">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:sld) > 0) and (count(ancestor::r/preceding-sibling::node[1][@lvl='1'])) > 0">
        <bulleted>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </bulleted>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:sld) > 0) and (count(ancestor::r/preceding-sibling::node[1][@lvl='2'])) > 0">
        <bulleted2>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </bulleted2>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:notes) > 0) and (count(ancestor::r/preceding-sibling::node[1][@lvl='2'])) > 0">
        <bulleted>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </bulleted>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:notes) > 0) and (count(ancestor::r/preceding-sibling::node[1][@lvl='3'])) > 0">
        <bulleted2>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </bulleted2>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <bodytext>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </bodytext>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the desired XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <bodytext>header text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>body text </bodytext>
    <bodytext>body text </bodytext>
    <bodytext>body text </bodytext>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted2>bulleted2 text</bulleted2>
    <bulleted2>bulleted2 text</bulleted2>
    <bulleted2>bulleted2 text</bulleted2>
    <bulleted2>bulleted2 text</bulleted2>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bulleted>bulleted text</bulleted>
    <bodytext>body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>footer text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>10</bodytext>
    <bodytext>10</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes header text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes body text </bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes body text </bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table header text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table header text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
    <bodytext>notes table body text</bodytext>
</document>
```

Comment: Please minimize your example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: That would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems with your attempt and fixing these should cause the XSLT to work as expected:

- You are missing the namespace prefix on `ancestor::r`. It should be `ancestor::a:r`.
- You are using `preceding-sibling::node` instead of `preceding-sibling::node()`. The former will only select elements named "node", of which there are none.

  - However, you should actually be using `preceding-sibling::*` instead of either of those two, lest the whitespace text nodes get in the way.

All that said, your approach can be cleaned up a lot by making use of variables and getting rid of that unnecessary `count(...) > 0` stuff. The following should produce the expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:t"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:t">
    <xsl:variable name="sld" select="ancestor::p:sld" />
    <xsl:variable name="notes" select="ancestor::p:notes" />
    <xsl:variable name="levelBeforeR"
                  select="ancestor::a:r/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lvl" />

    <xsl:variable name="wrapperName">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sld   and $levelBeforeR = '1' or
                        $notes and $levelBeforeR = '2'">
          <xsl:text>bulleted</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sld   and $levelBeforeR = '2' or
                        $notes and $levelBeforeR = '3'">
          <xsl:text>bulleted2</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>bodytext</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$wrapperName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up Is there a simple way to expand this to wrap the contents of the first `a:t` descendant of each p:sld with the tag `<foo>` and the first `a:t` descendant of each `p:notes` with the tag `<bar>`? This instead of (not addition to) the other wrapping tag that would normally apply.

Comment: Decided to post that as entirely new question. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130774/selecting-first-descendant-of-a-certain-name-for-each-instance-of-a-particular-a)

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, `ancestor::r` looks wrong.  At least OSX has a perl utility, `xpath`, and you can test select statemtents.  I had to replace `::r` with `::a:r` since there's no `r` node in your source XML:

```
~ zyoung$ xpath so.xml "//a:t[ancestor::p:sld and ancestor::r]"
No nodes found
~ zyoung$ xpath so.xml "//a:t[ancestor::p:sld and ancestor::a:r]"
Found 18 nodes:
-- NODE --
<a:t>header text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>body text </a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>body text </a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>body text </a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted2 text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted2 text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted2 text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted2 text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>bulleted text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>body text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>body text</a:t>-- NODE --
<a:t>footer text</a:t>
```

Without doing any more work, I'm guessing that:

1. the `preceding...` in `ancestor::r/preceding-sibling::node[1][@lvl='1']` should actually be a predicate of `a:r`, and not a path of `a:r`
2. the `count()` functions are unecessary, as my XPath example proves... one of the most basic XSL tests is "does a node exist" (some number of nodes > 0), so `test="a"` implies `test="count(a) > 0"` without all...
3. the parens, which also looked messed up (e.g., `)) > 0"`, why is the `> 0` **outside** of the last paren?); just do away with `count()` until you actually care about the exact number of elements