# Selecting first descendant of a certain name for each instance of a particular ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some complex MS-Office XML that looks like what you see at the link but the full source is much longer with many `p:sld` and `p:notes` children of document root. Always appearing in the order `p:sld`, `p:notes`, `p:sld`, `p:notes` http://pastie.org/9604783

Thanks to JLRishe, I have some xsl that extracts descendant `a:t` elements and wraps their contents in various tags based on context.

That XSL is as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:t"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:t">
    <xsl:variable name="sldAncestor" select="ancestor::p:sld" />
    <xsl:variable name="notesAncestor" select="ancestor::p:notes" />
    <xsl:variable name="rAncestorPreLevel"
                  select="ancestor::a:r/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lvl" />

    <xsl:variable name="wrapperName">
      <xsl:choose>

         <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '1'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '2'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '3'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet2</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '0'"  >
          <xsl:text>StudentNotes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

         <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '1'"  >
          <xsl:text>StudentNotes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '2'">
          <xsl:text>Student_Notes_Bullet</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '3'">
          <xsl:text>Student_Notes_Bullet_1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>Body</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$wrapperName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I want to expand that be able to select the first `a:t` element that appears inside of each `p:sld` and wrap that in the tags `<SlideTitleGhost></SlideTitleGhost>`.

Similarly I want to be able to select the first `a:t` element inside each `p.notes` element 
and wrap its contents with the tags `<PageBreak /><StudentNotes></StudentNotes>`

Note that not all `a:t` elements are siblings. Sibling `a:t` elements are children of `a:r` elements but there are multiple `a:r` elements descended from each `p:notes` or `p:sld` element. And those `a:r` elements cannot be expected to be siblings either. The last part of the xpath to each `a:t` element goes `//p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t`

I'm using Saxon-HE on windows but could switch processors if needed.

The desired output would look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <SlideTitleGhost>header text</SlideTitleGhost>
    <Body>body text </Body>
    <Body>body text </Body>
    <Body>body text </Body>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet1>bulleted2 text</SlideBullet1>
    <SlideBullet1>bulleted2 text</SlideBullet1>
    <SlideBullet1>bulleted2 text</SlideBullet1>
    <SlideBullet1>bulleted2 text</SlideBullet1>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <SlideBullet>bulleted text</SlideBullet>
    <Body>body text</Body>
    <Body>body text</Body>
    <Body>footer text</Body>
    <Body>10</Body>
    <Body>10</Body>
    <PageBreak />
    <StudentNotes>notes header text</StudentNotes>
    <Body>notes body text</Body>
    <StudentNotes>notes body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table header text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table header text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>table body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table body text</StudentNotes>
    <StudentNotes>notes table body text</StudentNotes>
</document>
```

Comment: Set up templates for each case, adjust template priorities so the exceptions get matched before the default case does.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get close enough to a desired outcome (and get rid of the last a:t element under each p:sld) with the following XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:t"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:t">
    <xsl:variable name="sldAncestor" select="ancestor::p:sld" />
    <xsl:variable name="notesAncestor" select="ancestor::p:notes" />
    <xsl:variable name="rAncestorPreLevel" select="ancestor::a:r/preceding-sibling::a:pPr/@lvl" />
    <xsl:variable name="SlideTitle" select="ancestor::p:txBody/preceding-sibling::p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph/@type" />

    <xsl:variable name="wrapperName"> 

    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '1'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '2'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '3'">
          <xsl:text>SlideBullet2</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sldAncestor and $SlideTitle = 'title'">
          <xsl:text>SlideTitleGhost</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and not(ancestor::a:r/preceding-sibling::a:pPr/@lvl)">
          <xsl:text>StudentNotes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

         <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '1'"  >
          <xsl:text>StudentNotes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '2'">
          <xsl:text>Student_Notes_Bullet</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and $rAncestorPreLevel = '3'">
          <xsl:text>Student_Notes_Bullet_1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>SlideTopic</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not($notesAncestor and ancestor::a:fld)">
           <xsl:element name="{$wrapperName}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="." />
           </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$notesAncestor and ancestor::a:fld">
        <xsl:element name="PageBreak"></xsl:element>
           </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did it by identifying the unique condition that was true of each and only each first `a:t` descendant element of a `p:sld` element (`ancestor::p:txBody/preceding-sibling::p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph/@type`). The second `xsl:choose` added to the bottom let me throw out the last `a:t` in each `p:sld`, which I didn't want to include in output anyway as it was not needed with the output, and use that as the moment to insert a `<pagebreak>` tag which I did want before the first `a:t` descendant of a `p:notes`.

**Update:** it turns out this isn't a solution because document order doesn't match the order the text appears on the page from top to bottom in the source PowerPoint document on many pages. The title text that appears at the top of each slide appears as an `a:t` element after other `a:t` elements in doc order in many cases.

I'm working on a solution to apply two different templates based on whether the child of the root is `p:sld` or `p:notes`. Applying template to `"p:sld|p:notes"` when the context is the root element.

If it slects `p:sld` the xslt looks up the value of the descendant a:t that would get wrapped in `<SlideTitleGhost>`, stores that value in a variable, then outputs the `<SlideTitleGhost>`$variable`</SlideTitleGhost>` followed by applying template for descendant `a:t` elements as described above, except that a:t elements which would have their contents wrapped in `<SlideTitleGhost>` are dropped.

If it selects `p:notes` it simply applies the template for `a:t`. `<PageBreak></PageBreak>` that marks the start of a `p:notes` is already being inserted when the last `a:t` element is being dropped.

Currently though I'm getting empty output. So any advice on how to what I'm describing above would be welcome.